# Momentum scrolling on iOS (-webkit-overflow-scrolling) takes everything else with it

Tags: ios, css, safari, mobile-safari, css-position

I'm using the technique in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/) to add momentum/intertia scrolling to an element.

html:

```
<h1>My title</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cause">
    <div class="cause-content">
      <h2>things</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cause">
    <div class="cause-content">
      <h2>things</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="cause">
    <div class="cause-content">
      <h2>things</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cause">
    <div class="cause-content">
      <h2>things</h2>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="cause">
    <div class="cause-content">
      <h2>things</h2>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="cause">
    <div class="cause-content">
      <h2>things</h2>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="cause">
    <div class="cause-content">
      <h2>things</h2>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="cause">
    <div class="cause-content">
      <h2>things</h2>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container{
  margin-top: 5em;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.cause{
  /* prettify */
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;

  /* real shit */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 260px
}
```

This works, but the problem is that it takes other elements with it! My title scrolls off with it. This happens even if I add `position: fixed` (probably because fixed isn't fully supported on iOS Safari.

Does anybody know of a way to get inertia scrolling working while still jeeping the other elements in the right place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by using the code [in this pen](http://codepen.io/benfrain/pen/vGetI/). The important bit seems to be the `whitespace: no-wrap` bit.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="" class="internal">item 1</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 2</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 3</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 4</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 5</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 6</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 320px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.internal {
  display: inline;
  background-color: wheat;
  &:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
}
```